# How to use spring dependency injection in our web service

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

We have a web service that we are trying to reimplement using Spring DI.

Here is how it works:
On each request that the web service receives in the controller, based off the page name, we instantiate a handler to get the list of tasks that can handle the request.

```
interface Handler {
    List<Task> getTaskList();
}

class Controller {
    //Inject handler
    Handler handler;

    processrequest(){
        handler.getTasklist() -> execute
    }
}
```

We have about 5-6 such handler and we want the corresponding handler to be injected into the controller based on the request pagename.

Whats the best way to go about this? 
How do I inject a different handler on the fly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create the handlers in the configuration (or annotate your service implementations):

```
@Bean
public Handler handler1() {
    // return handler 1
}

@Bean
public Handler handler2() {
    // return handler 2
}
```

2a- Inject the `ApplicationContext` into your controller. Retrieve the required service based on the request mapping.

```
class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/handler1")
    processrequest(){
        Handler handler = context.getBean("handler1");
        handler.getTasklist() -> execute
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/handler2")
    processrequest(){
        Handler handler = context.getBean("handler2");
        handler.getTasklist() -> execute
    }
}
```

2b- Alternatively, create multiple controllers, and inject the appropriate handler.

```
@RequestMapping("/handler1")
class Controller1 {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handler1")
    private Handler handler;

    processrequest(){
        handler.getTasklist() -> execute
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/handler2")
class Controller2 {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handler2")
    private Handler handler;

    processrequest(){
        handler.getTasklist() -> execute
    }
}
```